# Redirect data from console to the python script

Tags: python, c++

I have .bat file which outputs data in console, than I need to read that data with  python script and run through "if cycles"

The question is: How to read that data with python script?

Comment: Show what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you might take:

1. Use a pipe (the `|` character) in your command line to redirect the output that is going to the console to the Python script, and code the Python script to read from `stdin`.
2. Redirect the output that is going to the console to a file (with `>filename`) and then code the Python script to read from that file.

Comment: import subprocess

cmd = r'c:\Test.bat'

PIPE = subprocess.PIPE

p = subprocess.Popen([cmd, r'/?'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

p.communicate()

How to use stdin read here? I'm beginner, so I would be really pleased, if you help me to make out

Comment: Import `sys` and read from `sys.stdin`; you don't have to open it.  The pipe should be used in the command line in your batch file.